# PostMessage for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, postmessage

I've written a few programs on Windows which utilise PostMessage to send keystrokes and mouse events to a target application. I cannot find a way to do this on Linux except possibly using DBus, but what I've seen so far suggests that I would need the target applications window to be focused.

The other alternative I've found is X11 API (keysym.h), but this also appears to require a focused window.

Is there a way to send mouse/keyboard events to a window which is not in focus on Linux?

Comment: Google has _so many_ results for this.

Comment: Could you use interprocess communication (like sockets, message queues etc.) for that?

Comment: @Lightness Google does have a few results but none for Linux which don't require focus. Simulating the keyboard is easy, sending keyboard signals to an application not so (at least as I've experienced).

Comment: @sigalor sadly not, the target process is not my own. While I could inject some shared object file and call the message handler manually, it would be intrusive, version dependant, and require far more reverse engineering than I'm comfortable with right now.

Comment: [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)

Comment: No, it is not required that the target window has focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got it right, you want method how to trigger event to application, which is running on X server. There are many methods, how to do it. One of most easier is throw tool known as `xdotool`.

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

### Example:

```
xdotool type --window Firefox hello
```

This shall send 'hello' trigger keyboard sequence without focusing `Firefox` itself.